# Сохранение поступающего post запроса PHP

Tags: php

Час добрый
Подскажите пожалуйста как при помощи php можно обработать поступающий запрос в виде json данных. Json который отправляют при помощи post запроса выглядит следующим образом:

```
{'source': 'ok parse mskmigrant', 'contact': '79999999999', 'info': 'У вас есть РВП или ВНЖ?: (Есть ВНЖ)\nГде вы сейчас находитесь?: (Московская область)\nВыберите ваше текущее гражданство: ( )\n', 'query_info': {'question1': 'У вас есть РВП или ВНЖ?', 'answer1': 'Есть ВНЖ', 'question2': 'Где вы сейчас находитесь?', 'answer2': 'Московская область', 'question3': 'Выберите ваше текущее гражданство:', 'answer3': ' '}, 'type': 'ok parse', 'name': 'Алекс Иванов', 'nameurl': 'https://ok.ru/profile/609999999999', 'formname': ' Консультация для граждан Таджикистана', 'created_at': '1653900240000'}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно его сохранить в txt файл при помощи php чтобы получить примерно следующий вид:

```
@source@
 ok parse mskmigran

@contact@
79999999999

@info@
У вас есть РВП или ВНЖ?: (Есть ВНЖ)\n
Где вы сейчас находитесь?: (Московская область)\n
Выберите ваше текущее гражданство: ( )\n',

@query_info@
question1: У вас есть РВП или ВНЖ?\n
answer1: Есть ВНЖ\n
question2: Где вы сейчас находитесь?
answer2: Московская область
question3: Выберите ваше текущее гражданство
answer3: 

@type@
ok parse

@name@
Алекс Иванов

@nameurl@
https://ok.ru/profile/601114

@formname@
Консультация для граждан Таджикистана

@created_at@
1653900240000
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вывод json ключей-значений в php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1441979/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-json-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-php)

Comment: Мне кажется за 4 дня уж давно можно было эту тему изучить самостоятельно и всё написать.... ну вот серьёзно............ тем более в предыдущем ответе почти всё есть......не хватает только вложенного цикла..... ну вот серьёзно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если и понятно, то только тем кто знаком с php. Я же в свою очередь даже понять не могу где не хватает вложенного цикла и что именно с ним нужно сделать

Comment: очевидно там, где есть вложенность......для этого знакомство с php вообще не требуется. от слова совсем

Comment: @АлексейШиманский для того чтобы определить место где нужно прописать цикл - нужно знать как его определить. Я абсолютно не знаком с синтаксисом языка и не разбираюсь в нем. В питоне или js без проблем за пару строчек напишу вывод всех данных, но не с php

Comment: Причём тут синтаксис какого-то языка, если у тебя данные представлены в виде JSON? ......  то есть ты знаком с JS, но не знаешь, как посмотреть структуру JSON, чтоб посмотреть где нужен ещё цикл?  REALLY? ........

Comment: Ну вот напиши это на обычных циклах в JS , и переложи это на PHP. Будет почти один в один

Comment: @АлексейШиманский господи, да при чем здесь структура json. Я в душе не чаю как вывести этот поступающий json при помощи php и все. Если бы разобрался погуглив то явно бы не плодил темы здесь

Comment: foreach as key => val........ all you need   ....и один if

Comment: Ой да ладно...... это на столько элементарно, что пишется почти одинаково на всех языках (всякие GO , Haskel не в счёт).  На JS, PHP, C#, Java и пр  как минимум это выглядит почти одинаково......просто кто-то не хочет вникать....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский За место обсуждения можете пожалуйста подредактировать тот код что вы отправили выше? По тому что я понимаю о том что там было написано в  $data наполняли данными в формате ключ:значение. И то если = присуждает значение, а не добавляет, то по сути оно каждый раз переписывает данные в data. Это все что я от туда понял. Так же учитывая что     $items = json_decode($json, true); в онлайн редакторах возвращают None за место данных. Если бы я знал как это исправить -я бы не создавал пост и не писал комментарии

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если вы разбираетесь в этом, то почему за место бесполезной полемики просто бы не написали как это должно выглядеть? Для вас очевидно как это сделать, для меня - нет.

Comment: "в онлайн редакторах возвращают None за место данных" --- потому что писать нужно правильно....я имею в виду сам JSON.......   https://onlinephp.io/c/25967

Answer (score -2):

1)Спарсить данные спомощьюэкспройда, по сепараторам "," и заголовки по ":"

```
explode()
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php
2)Массив в цикле по строчно записать в файл txt

```
fopen()
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php

Comment: Если ты парсишь json с помощью `explode` - у меня для тебя очень плохие новости.